# The new gold and bronze badges are too close in color

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, badges

The colors of the gold and bronze badges in this design are too close in color and hard to distinguish.

Here's a screenshot from the header:
[image: header]

Here's a screenshot from the badges page

[image: listing]

Comment: @rchern: Thanks for adding the images. On second look, I don't feel as strongly about it as I originally did.

Comment: When they're next to each other, they're not hard to tell apart. But if you only see a bronze badge, it's hard to decide if it's bronze or a rich orangeish gold.

Answer (score 2):

While color is a subjective thing, I can't really see this.